# Написание своих приложений под Huawei Watch FIt 2 (HarmonyOS)

Tags: huawei

Есть-ли какая-то возможность писать свои приложения для смарт часов Huawei Watch Fit 2?

Comment: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/connectivity-guides/dev-process-0000001051058039